# Update HTML file based on JSP file contents

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a JSP file which includes a form with the following input types: a password field, and 2 text input fields. This page will only be visible to a moderator so that the moderator may type in the password and only then will she be able to modify any contents. After the moderator modifies the contents, the updated contents will be written to a text file, and then the contents are extracted from the text file and placed on a div for the moderator to view. This is all in one jsp file. Here is my code for the file reader portion:

```
<%
    String file = "/docs/file.jsp";
    FileReader read = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(read);
    scan.useDelimiter("\n");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
      list.add(scan.next());

     for(int i=(list.size()-2); i<list.size(); i++)
    {
       %>
         <div id="contact"> <%=list.get(i)%> </div> <%
      }
     scanner.close();
 } %>
```

I have a few .html files that I would like to update as soon as the moderator makes changes. For example, if she changes the business phone number and fax number, I want the changes to be visible automatically in the Contact Us page, About page, etc. The html file looks like this:

```
<div>
<p> 1-800-888-8888 </p>
</div>
```

I know that if I include an `href` tag linking to the .jsp file, the input fields will be visible to the users, which I don't want. I just want them to see the updated phone numbers all around the site. Would I have to include the "contact" div from my .jsp file in the .html file? And if so, how would I go about doing that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the changes to be visible automatically in the Contact Us page

Just make the *Contact Us* page a JSP, which extracts the phone number from where you have stored it. JSPs is for *dynamic* web pages, which have automatically changing content. That is what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [**Java Beans**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javabeans/info) When the value is updated . You can set them to the setters . You can retrieve the values through [**JSTL**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) or **[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)**

Hope it helps!!